# URL redirection with webapp2

Tags: google-app-engine, webapp2

I'm developing an application with `webapp2` to be deployed on Google App Engine. URLs will always be preceded by a language identifier, such as:

- http://www.mydomain.com/en/foo
- http://www.mydomain.com/en/bar

I would like to automatically redirect any request that doesn't start with a language identifier to the corresponding English version. For example, the following URLs should redirect to the URLs above:

- http://www.mydomain.com/foo
- http://www.mydomain.com/bar

Currently, I'm using [`webapp2_extras`](http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/api/webapp2_extras/routes.html) to set up one redirect for every possible URL, which is creating a lot of code duplication. The problem is that, to my understanding, URL redirection in `webapp2` needs to be defined on a per-handler basis.

How can I go about redirecting all requests that don't match a regular expression (language identifier in my case) to the corresponding modified URL (adding `en/` in my case)?

Comment: Shouldn't you do language detection, and redirect based on the user's preference?

Comment: @Nick Yep, that will come a bit later. At our first launch, we'll only have English support.

Answer (score 0):

what you are searching for is a middlware. [here](http://www.morethanseven.net/2009/03/18/simple-wsgi-middleware-app-engine.html) an example.

Answer (score 0):

Old question but it seems like setting routes and catching exceptions would be a good way to go for this: http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/exceptions.html#exceptions-in-the-wsgi-app

Routes for the http://www.mydomain.com/en/foo cases and any http://www.mydomain.com/foo cases will be a 404 exception, which you can address with a handler, redirecting to the appropriate "en" page.